# Space required for integer and float data types in InfluxDB

Tags: int, size, influxdb

I need to find a theoretical size of each record inserted into InfluxDB. Supposing I have 10 integer fields and 30 float fields, then how much space should it theoretically require, disregarding tags and compression?

I have read that float and integer take up one word, which will be 64 bits on a 64 bit system, but I am doubtful, after reading this open issue (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7801).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed Integer to use 64 bits and Float to use > 32 bits on InfluxDB 1.7.3 running on a 64-bit Mac. Hence, I am concluding both, integer and float data types in Influx to use 64-bits or 8-bytes.